# Passing DOM objects af function arguments

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making three divs replacing each other and wrote this code, but it stops on calling swapdivs function inside the x.onclick function. swapdivs(divstart,divcloud) works fine in console. I suspect I pass in wrong way DOM object variables, or some scope problem but got stuck:

```
    <h2><a href="#" id="cloudclick">Cloud Services</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#" id="telecomclick">IT Consulting</a></h2>
    <div id="info-columns-container">
      <div id="info-column-start"> .... </div>
      <div id="info-column-cloud-services" >  .... </div>
      <div id="info-column-telecom" >  .... </div>
    </div>

  <script>

  var mydivs = document.getElementById('info-columns-container');
  var divstart = document.getElementById('info-column-start');
  var divcloud = document.getElementById('info-column-cloud-services');
  var divtelecom = document.getElementById('info-column-telecom');

  function swapdivs (divout, divin) {
    divout.parentNode.removeChild(divout);
    mydivs.appendChild(divin);
    return false;
  }

  divcloud.parentNode.removeChild(divcloud);
  divtelecom.parentNode.removeChild(divtelecom); 
  var currdiv = "start";

  document.getElementById('cloudclick').onclick = function () {
    if (currdiv == "start") {swapdivs(divstart,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";} 
    if (currdiv == "cloud") {swapdivs(divcloud,divstart); currdiv = "start";}
    if (currdiv == "telecom") {swapdivs(divtelecom,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";}
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById('telecomclick').onclick = function () {
    if (currdiv == "start") {swapdivs(divstart,divtelecom); currdiv = "telecom";} 
    if (currdiv == "cloud") {swapdivs(divcloud,divtelecom); currdiv = "telecom";}
    if (currdiv == "telecom") {swapdivs(divtelecom,divstart); currdiv = "start";}
    return false;
  }


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements need to be `if/else` statements.  So, this:

```
  document.getElementById('cloudclick').onclick = function () {
    if (currdiv == "start") {swapdivs(divstart,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";} 
    if (currdiv == "cloud") {swapdivs(divcloud,divstart); currdiv = "start";}
    if (currdiv == "telecom") {swapdivs(divtelecom,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";}
    return false;
  }
```

should be:

```
  document.getElementById('cloudclick').onclick = function () {
    if (currdiv == "start") {swapdivs(divstart,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";} 
    else if (currdiv == "cloud") {swapdivs(divcloud,divstart); currdiv = "start";}
    else if (currdiv == "telecom") {swapdivs(divtelecom,divcloud); currdiv = "cloud";}
    return false;
  }
```

The issue is that if your first `if` statement executes, then it changes the value of `currdiv` which then causes the next `if` statement to also fire which I don't think is what you want because it reverses what the previous statement just did.  The change to `if/else` will will make sure that only one of your conditions executes at once.

Comment: How silly I am. Greatly appreciate your help jfriend00 !

Comment: BTW,, only if not much trouble or effort, is there a way to animate this type of page change using CSS transitions? I googled and found that straight CSS transitions do not work..

Comment: @Maxx - it depends entirely upon what kind of animation you want to do - you'd have to explain further what you want.  Since it looks like you're relatively new here, do you understand about selecting a "best answer" when someone answers your question?  That earns both you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points which earn you privileges here on SO as you accumulate points.